# How does nforce store query responses

Tags: nforce

I was trying to play around with [this](https://github.com/jeffdonthemic/node-nforce-demo) nforce demo but I'm having trouble figuring out how to reference data I get back from queries. The following appears to query for info that gets displayed on the home page:

```
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {

  org.query({ query: "Select Id, Name, Type, Industry, Phone, Email From Account Order By LastModifiedDate DESC" })
    .then(function(results){
      res.render('index', { records: results.records });
    });

});
```

Which is displayed in a table using:

```
{{#each records}}
<tr>
  <td>
    ...
  </td>
  <td><a href="/{{get this 'Id'}}">{{get this 'Name'}}</a> {{{badge this 'Rating'}}}</td>
  <td>{{get this 'Type'}}</td>
  <td>{{get this 'Industry'}}</td>
</tr>
{{/each}}
```

Why can't I change one of these td's to `{{get this 'Phone'}}` and have the phone number displayed? I see Phone is included in the query, but I don't understand where/if it's stored.

Answer (score 3):

You're mis-reading the code it seems. The query for home page does NOT include Phone.

```
/* home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {

  org.query({ query: "Select Id, Name, Type, Industry, Rating From Account Order By LastModifiedDate DESC" })
    .then(function(results){
      res.render('index', { records: results.records });
    });

});
```

It is however included in the query for record detail page (and that's probably what you mistook for home page)

```
/* Record detail page */
router.get('/:id', function(req, res, next) {
  // query for record, contacts and opportunities
  Promise.join(
    org.getRecord({ type: 'account', id: req.params.id }),
    org.query({ query: "Select Id, Name, Email, Title, Phone From Contact where AccountId = '" + req.params.id + "'"}),
    org.query({ query: "Select Id, Name, StageName, Amount, Probability From Opportunity where AccountId = '" + req.params.id + "'"}),
    function(account, contacts, opportunities) {
        res.render('show', { record: account, contacts: contacts.records, opps: opportunities.records });
    });
});
```

And you can see it's being shown on the record detail using the show.hbs template

```
<table class="slds-table slds-table--bordered slds-max-medium-table--stacked-horizontal">
          <thead>
            <tr class="slds-no-hover">
              <th class="slds-text-heading--label slds-size--1-of-4" scope="col">Name</th>
              <th class="slds-text-heading--label slds-size--1-of-4" scope="col">Title</th>
              <th class="slds-text-heading--label slds-size--1-of-4" scope="col">Email</th>
              <th class="slds-text-heading--label slds-size--1-of-4" scope="col">Phone</th>
              <th class="slds-row-action" scope="col">
                <button class="slds-button slds-button--icon-border-filled slds-button--icon-border-small">
                  <svg aria-hidden="true" class="slds-button__icon slds-button__icon--hint slds-button__icon--small">
                    <use xlink:href="/assets/icons/utility-sprite/svg/symbols.svg#down"></use>
                  </svg>
                  <span class="slds-assistive-text">Show More</span>
                </button>
              </th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            {{#each contacts}}
```

Comment: I've since modified the query under `/* home page */` to include phone, but I'm still having the same issue. the `res.render(...)` is confusing me tbh

Comment: The first argument there is the name of your hbs template - so you might be using index there for home page. For record detail, it is set to show. The 2nd argument refers to a collection of records. If you added the phone field to home page, you also need to add it to index.hbs and then it will show up.

Answer (score 0):

FYI, the slightly unusual (to me anyway) syntax of e.g.:

```
{{get this 'Type'}}
```

looks like it comes from this Handlebars helper [node-nforce-demo/lib/hbsHelpers.js](https://github.com/jeffdonthemic/node-nforce-demo/blob/master/lib/hbsHelpers.js) function:

```
hbs.registerHelper('get', function(record, field) {
    return record.get(field);
});
```

so its really just a `get` function of an individual `{{#each records}}` record.